# Why won't Bundler install vPim?

Tags: ruby, dependencies, bundler, vpim

I have the following in my `Gemfile`:

```
clear_sources
bundle_path "vendor/bundler_gems"

source "http://gemcutter.org"
...
gem "vpim",                 "~> 0.658"
# a whole bunch of other gems
```

When I run `gem bundle`, I get everything installed except vpim. Running `gem bundle --list | grep vpim` returns nothing.

I'm using `bundler08` because the project can't be upgraded to Bundler 0.9 yet.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by installing vPim manually (`gem install vpim --version "~> 0.658"`) and then copying the gem specification to my bundled gems directory. Bonus points for anyone who figures out why Bundler didn't copy the specification.